# How to import types from @types/google-apps-script?

Tags: typescript, google-apps-script

Trying to type `sheet` and `columnName` using types from [@types/google-apps-script](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/google-apps-script).

```js
import {} from "google-apps-script" // File '/Users/johndoe/test/node_modules/@types/google-apps-script/index.d.ts' is not a module.ts(2306) 

const getColumnIdByName = (sheet, columnName) => {
  const headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0]
  for (let index = 0; index < headers.length; index++) {
    if (headers[index] === columnName) {
      return index + 1
    }
  }
  return null
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out… no need for `import`.

```
const getColumnIdByName = (
  sheet: GoogleAppsScript.Spreadsheet.Sheet,
  columnName: string
) => {
  const headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0]
  for (let index = 0; index < headers.length; index++) {
    if (headers[index] === columnName) {
      return index + 1
    }
  }
  return null
}
```

Using following `tsconfig.json`.

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "target": "ESNext"
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*"]
}
```

Comment: `GoogleAppsScript` is a global I guess, so you don't need the import. If you do, the incantation is: `import type * from "google-apps-script";`

Answer (score 0):

```
{
  "isolatedModules": true,
  "noLib": true,
  "noResolve": true,
  "target": "ES3",
  "module": "None",
  "noImplicitUseStrict": true,
  "experimentalDecorators": true,
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please explain how this answer the question.